# Javascript array inside another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, ionic-framework

I am starting with the ionic framework and I am stuck in creating and calling an array inside another array.

I have the following code in my `books.js` :

```
.factory('Books', function() {

  // books data
  var books = [{
    id: 0,
    title: 'Sample Title',
    author: 'Sample Author',
    category: 'Horor, Fiction',
    cover: '/cover.jpeg',
    details: 'some details about the book',
    // my first attempt to create an array to store chapters info
    chapters: [
      {
        name: 'Chapter 1',
        filename: 'chapter1.html',
      },
      {
        name: 'Chapter 2',
        filename: 'Chapter2.html',
      }
    ]
  }, {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Sample Title Two',
    author: 'Sample Author two',
    category: 'Horor, Fiction',
    cover: '/cover.jpeg',
    details: 'some details about the book',
    // my first attempt to create an array to store chapters info
    chapters: [
      {

        name: 'Chapter 1',
        filename: 'chapter1.html',
      },
      {
        name: 'Chapter 2',
        filename: 'Chapter2.html',
      }
    ]
  },
```

when accessing data, I use `{{book.title}}` and it will output the title of the book. But I am not sure how to return the chapters values since each book has different numbers of chapters.

Perhaps assign a chapter ID for each chapter and call that ID ?

Comment: have you tried book.chapters[0].name ?

Comment: books[0].chapters[0].name

Comment: Where want to show it? on the html with angular? if so try with an ng repeat directive.

Comment: @FacundoPedrazzini can you elaborate on how to use ng-repeat for chapters in the items?

Comment: @JeanCedron thanks :) `{{book.chapters[book.id].name}}` actually worked. But it only shows 1 chapter in the list

Comment: `book.chapters.forEach(function(chapter){console.log(chapter.name)});`

Comment: @RainMan see the answers. Good luck

Comment: @RainMan Is it possible to share html snippet for this part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to show it on Angular

```
<div ng-repeat="book in books">
    {{book.title}}
    <div ng-repeat="chapter in book.chapters">
        {{chapter.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```